# Applying Background Resources from SDCARD

Tags: android

I am trying to find a way to apply background resources to several buttons. These resources are from the SDCARD. The usual way of applying resources is this:

```
Button b = new Button(getContext());
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_states);
//where button_states is an XML file
```

But I do not know how to apply a background, if the XML file is from the sdcard. Any ideas?

Comment: are you storing the xml file in the sdcard and trying to use it?

Comment: Yes sharath G, I am storing the XML in the sdcard

Comment: Can i know the need to store a xml file in the sdcard @Jayson Tamayo

Comment: I am creating buttons dynamically so if push an update, I'll just have to download the resources(xml) and save it on the sdcard.

Comment: So do you have the downloaded content as an xml file itself?
and its something like styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for that, it may help you.

```
Button b = new Button(getContext());
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/test.png");
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
b.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String rootPath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); // Returns path to sdcard
rootPath+="/test.png"
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing xml files in sdcard use something like this

```
<selector>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#343434"
            android:endColor="#171717"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#171717" />
        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Try using this as a seperate xml file in the drawable folder and apply it to the required button like

```
style="@style/ButtonText
```

in the layout xml file